# WPF Object Bound UI Control

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

Being relatively new to WPF, I was impressed with the DataGrid's ability to auto-generate columns when bound to a collection of Objects in the ViewModel.

One question this feature raised was whether there was a similar control that could be bound to a single object instance. This would 'auto-generate' an input form off the object with suitable controls based on types.

The closest thing I have seen to this is Django's excellent ability to generate forms off an underlying model with accompanying validation.

Answer (score 0):

autogenerate - no, but with a DataTemplate you can visualize all objects you want.